# IOS Swift: Scrolling child views doesnt scroll the parent view

Tags: ios, uicontainerview

My iOS app view has a cover Image at top (100% width, 30% height) and a Table for the rest of the screen. To acheive this kind of layout, I am using "Container Views" in my view. So I have Two Container Views:
1st Container is normal view controller with UIImage.
2nd Container is Table View Controller. This can have many entries.

When I run this and try to scroll, only the second container scrolls in place. 1st container remains at the top.

How can I make the full parent view to scroll instead of just second view.
(Are container views right bet for this kind of requirement and layout?)

Comment: What're container views ? Your case is looking like a simple UITableView with a header view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may create a new cell called "HeaderImageCell", and make the first cell to be "headerImageCell"

"Container Views" is not needed at this point.